# Charset in index page with SQL queries

Tags: php, mysql, utf-8, character

In my index.php I have some fixed text written with specialchars (for ex. è à ä ö).
I also have a query wich post text coming from a database. This text has also spcialchars.
The database is setted with utf8_unicode_ci. I tried also utf8_general_ci and utf8_bin

If I place

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf8" />
```

on the header the plain text displays perfect (so I read è à ä ö).
On the other hand the text coming from the database is not displayed properly (I read ???).

Then If I place

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf8_unicode_ci" />
```

or

I have the database text posted perfectly, but the plain text from the HTML document is posted qui thos À À À instead of the specialchars àéè.

What am I doing wrong?

EDIT:

I tried with:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf8" />
```

and then when I connect to the db:

```
$connection->set_charset('utf8');
```

The results are displayed properly. Is this a good solution?

Comment: Yes, your edit is not only good, but the correct solution. Incorrect deceptive solutions that appear initially to be working include using `utf8_encode/decode`.

Answer (score -1):

You could use utf8_encode() / utf8_decode() on the database text which should do the job ..

Comment: Can you explain me better your solution? Thank you!